# Is there a app like Flux for the Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was wondering if there is a app like i have on my Ubuntu laptop. To add a blue light filter. The program i use on my laptop is called Flux.
Is it possible to install the same app as i installed on my laptop, on my Ubuntu-phone?

Or is there another app that have the same options?

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work.

https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui

`git clone https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui.git`

`cd xflux-gui`

`sudo python setup.py install`

Then run from command-line

`fluxgui`